regex for expression with one separator hyphen
I'm going to use regex for matching expressions, which:

Separated by one (and only one) hyphen
Each of the two parts do not contain any spaces

So, it matches:
ss-ss
12-s2
11-11
%@2s-#1

And does not match:
s s-ss
ss-s s
s s-s s
1 s-1s
1s-1 s
1 s-1 s
ss-ss-ss
s1-s2-s3

Is there any way to create with regex?
I tries something like:
^.[^ ]-[^ ]*

But it matches only expressions with any number of hyphens, and whatever space occurrence, for example
 ss-ss-ss
 1 s-1 s


The regex:
'^[^\ \-]+\-[^\ \-]+$'

should do what you want. Here's the test that I did:
$ cat x.tst
ss-ss
12-s2
11-11
%@2s-#1
s s-ss
ss-s s
s s-s s
1 s-1s
1s-1 s
1 s-1 s
ss-ss-ss
s1-s2-s3

$ egrep  '^[^\ \-]+\-[^\ \-]+$' x.tst
ss-ss
12-s2
11-11
%@2s-#1

$ egrep  -v '^[^\ \-]+\-[^\ \-]+$' x.tst
s s-ss
ss-s s
s s-s s
1 s-1s
1s-1 s
1 s-1 s
ss-ss-ss
s1-s2-s3

An Explanation:
The problem is to recognize two non-empty strings separated by a hyphen. Those two strings can't have spaces or hyphens.

[xy]+ means "a string of 1 or more x's or y's"
[^xy]+ means "a string of 1 or more characters with no x's or y's
\ means "take the next character literally"
So, [^\ \-]+ means a non-empty string with no spaces or hyphens

We want that regex twice, separated by a hyphen.
^ at the front and $ at the end mean that the match has to extend for the entire string.
Without the ^ and $, "1 s-1 s" would be a match because the "s-1" in the middle would match the regex.

If you prefer, you can add parentheses to clarify the before and after part of the regex:
'^([^\ -]+)-([^\ -]+)$'
This would also allow referring to the before and after by usin \1 and \2 or $1 and $2

There's no need to escape - outside [].

please add an explaination to your anwer so future readers might adopt it more easily to their needs.

@DuesserBaest Added an explanation. Thanks for the suggestion.
